# Issue with Datetime.format('MM/DD/YYYY')

Tags: datetime, date

I have date field "dt" which debug like '2015-06-25', and I have to change the format like 06/25/2015. Since we can't use `.format('MM/DD/YYYY')` on date field. I have converted it to DateTime.

`DateTime dtt = datetime.newInstanace (dt.Year(),dt.month().dt.day()) ;`

Now when I debug dtt ,it's coming as 2015-06-25 07:00:00 , Don't know how 7 is coming. anyways 
when I try to change the format..

```
dtt.format('MM/DD/YYYY') is coming as 06/176/2015 but it should come 06/25/2015
```

please help . Thanks

Comment: Also note nearly always should be 'yyyy' not 'YYYY' per https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/404471/is-this-a-bug-in-apex-datetime-format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format method uses the [Java Simple Date Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) in which the meaning of D and d are different

D : Day in year

d : Day in month

so if you replace Capital D with small d it should work

Answer (score 0):

You already have a date 'as a date', not as a string. The format you are talking about (2015-06-25 07:00:00) is just a visual representation of a value contained in variable of a DateTime type. If you want the date to appear in the specified format (06/25/2015), just output it using format() method:

```
Datetime yourDate = Datetime.now();
String dateOutput = yourDate.format('dd/MM/yyyy');
```